# Why are MATLAB and matplotlib spectrogram value different?

Tags: matlab, python, spectrogram

I'm doing a signal processing to put data into my neural network.

I noticed a difference between  `MATLAB` and  `Python` spectrogram Value. I don't know why and ask questions.

This is `MATLAB` code

```
[y, Fs] = audioread('left (1).wav'); %1sec 16000 sample read

nwin  = 256; %16ms
novlp = 128; %8ms
nfft  = 256;

left = spectrogram(y, nwin, novlp, nfft, Fs, 'yaxis');
```

256-fft_point, 256 hamming window, 50% over lab, 16000 sampling rate

And This is `Python` code

```
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
from matplotlib import mlab

audio_sample, sampling_rate = sf.read("left (1).wav")

win = np.hamming(256)
Sxx, f, t = mlab.specgram(x=audio_sample, NFFT=256, Fs=sampling_rate, window=win, noverlap=128, mode='complex',
                          sides='default', detrend='none')

np.savetxt('C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/left_spec (1).txt', Sxx, delimiter=',')
```

It is also 256-fft_point, 256 hamming window, 50% over lab, 16000 sampling rate

However, the values are totally different as shown below.

[image]

In addition to the first four values, all values show different values.

When I read the wav file, the value seems to be the problem of the spectrogram function because both `MATLAB` and `Python` are the same.

I also changed the parameters of `Python` spectrogram function, tried post-processing such as Sxx = 10 * np.log10 (Sxx), and tried the spectrogram function of the scipy kit, but not all the same values as `MATLAB`.

Please help me, thank you for reading.

Comment: have you compared the documentations in Matlab and from matplotlib? my guess is that they simply do different things.

Comment: You might want to check [what data types are used in the derivation of the spectrogram too](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: Have you tried dividing the two? It looks to me like there might just be a constant factor between them, due to the way normalization is done.

Comment: have you find the solution? i am facing the same problem